# Anchor a RecyclerView little higher on a Collapsing Toolbar Layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Is it possible to anchor a RecyclerView a little bit higher than it's usual location, Like the FAB icon on most of the collapsible views (see Image 1 for the expected results).

[image: expected result]

**Image 1**

I tried the following code but it doesn't give the expected result (see Image 2 for the current result)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:expanded="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bannerImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:src="@drawable/starter_screen_bg"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Current result]

**Image 2**

Adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` attaches the recycler view to the Collapsible View, and then adding margin bottom is neglected.

But removing it gives the expected result, but then the scroll view does not behave as intended (no parallax effect) and scroll's after the background image scrolls.

So it is possible to achieve the collapsible view like the first image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy to achieve - there is a `behavior_overlapTop` property for each view that has `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`. So all you need to do is just to set this property to your `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/categories"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

[image]

Comment: I would not suggest 64dp specific height but use the ?attr/actionBarSize instead

Comment: But I mean why? It depends on the use case of the author, so was just an example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:expanded="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bannerImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:src="@drawable/starter_screen_bg"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="?actionBarSize"     // Changed Here only
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:gravity="center" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```